# Creating a subset between two numbers

Tags: r, filter, filtering

I'm trying to create a subset of data that exists between two ages.  I want data that has ages 25 to 29, but the existing set I have includes ages well beyond that range.  I am having much trouble trying to create this subset (I am new to R).

The script I'm using so far is:

```
cps_single_20s <- cps_single %>%
  filter(A_AGE < '25' |  A_AGE > '29')
```

Thank you for any help, this is really frustrating me.

Comment: I think you should remove quotation marks  in 25 and 29

Comment: Looks like that just gave me everything under 29 years old

Comment: `ps_single_20s <- cps_single %>%
  filter(A_AGE >25 &  A_AGE < 29)`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Worked perfectly!

Comment: You also had your logic wrong, <25 or >29 means you would be selecting exactly what you were NOT interested (>25 and <29)